# Run a function whose name is in a list

Tags: list, functional-programming, scheme, racket

I'm still learning Racket.

I have to call an unknown function. The function and its parameters are in the following list:

```
(define l1 '((function-name parameter1)
(function-name parameter3)))
```

To run that function, I'm doing:

```
(first (car l1)) (second (car l1)) another-parameter
```

But I get the error:

```
 application: not a procedure;
 expected a procedure that can be applied to arguments
  given: 'function-name
  arguments...:
```

How can I run that `function-name`?

**UPDATE:**

I have tried Óscar's answer:

```
(eval (first (car l1)) (second (car l1)) another-parameter)
```

And I get the error:

```
 eval: arity mismatch;
 the expected number of arguments does not match the given number
  given: 3
  arguments...:
```

I have also tried:

```
(define-namespace-anchor a)
(define ns (namespace-anchor->namespace a))
(eval (first (car l1)) (second (car l1)) another-parameter ns)
```

And I get the same error:

```
 eval: arity mismatch;
 the expected number of arguments does not match the given number
  given: 4
  arguments...:
```

Then, I tried this:

```
(eval (list (first (car l1)) (second (car l1)) another-parameter))
```

And I get the error:

```
function-name: unbound identifier;
 also, no #%app syntax transformer is bound in: function-name
```

Finally, I have tried:

```
(eval (list (first (car l1)) (second (car l1)) another-parameter) ns)
```

And I get an internal error from `function-name`. But this function, works perfectly.

`function-name` could be at least three functions (or more), this is why I haven't put it here before. All of them will have two lists as parameters, and they will return #t or #f.

One of then, then one is testing now is:

```
(define match (lambda (list1 list2) ...))
```

Obviously, `list1` and `list2` are lists.

**UPDATE 2:**
I have tried Óscar's Minimal, Complete and verifiable example, and it works. But, I have modified to used on my on work, and it doesn't work. Look:

```
(define function-name
  (lambda (list1 list2)
    (append list1 list2)))

(define parameter1 '(1 2))
(define parameter3 '(3 4))
(define another-parameter '(5 6))

(define l1 '((function-name parameter1)
             (function-name parameter3)))

(define-namespace-anchor a)
(define ns (namespace-anchor->namespace a))

(define another-function
  (lambda (l1 the-parameter)
    (cond
      [(eval (list (first (car l1)) (second (car l1)) 'the-parameter) ns) l1])
  )
)

(another-function l1 another-parameter)
```

I have created `another-function`, and it fails with the parameter `'the-parameter`. It complains saying:

```
the-parameter: undefined;
 cannot reference an identifier before its definition
```

So the problem is when I use a function's parameter as a parameter for the `eval` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`eval`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/eval.html) and [quasiquoting](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/quasiquote.html) for this, it works for your input. *Do* notice that this is how you should post your questions, it's a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that anyone can copy and run, without having to guess what you were thinking:

```
(define function-name
  (lambda (list1 list2)
    (append list1 list2)))

(define parameter1 '(1 2))
(define parameter3 '(3 4))
(define another-parameter '(5 6))

(define l1 '((function-name parameter1)
             (function-name parameter3)))

(define-namespace-anchor a)
(define ns (namespace-anchor->namespace a))

(define another-function
  (lambda (l1 the-parameter)
    (cond
      [(eval `(,(first (car l1)) ,(second (car l1)) ',the-parameter) ns)
       l1])))

(another-function l1 another-parameter)
=> '((function-name parameter1) (function-name parameter3))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have tried it and I get errors. I have updated my question. I'm testing the last error to know if it is my fault. Thanks.

Comment: As always: please post the real functions you’re using to test. At least an skeleton, so we know what parameters they’re expecting, etc.

Comment: This should work, and notice the quote before `another-parameter`: `(eval (list (first (car l1)) (second (car l1)) 'another-parameter) ns)`. If you still get an internal error from `function-name`, then there's something wrong with `function-name`, not with the way `eval` is doing its job.

Comment: I think I have found my problem. I have updated the question, but the problem is that I'm using as the parameter `another-parameter` a parameter from the function that `eval` is inside. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Done. Do you see the importance of giving all the context to an answer, and all the required procedures to make an MCV example? the real question was very different to what you posted before the two big edits.

Answer (score 4):

Please consider evaluating the procedure like this:

```scm
(define l1 `((,sin ,(+ 1 2))
             (,+ 1 2 3)))

(sin (+ 1 2))                 ; ==> 0.14..
((caar l1) (cadar l1))        ; ==> 0.14..
(apply (caar l1) (cdar l1))   ; ==> 0.14..

(+ 1 2 3)                     ; ==> 6
(apply (caadr l1) (cdadr l1)) ; ==> 6
```

Why does this work? Well. Your attempted to call the name of a procedure. By evaluating the procedure name you get the actual procedure object. You can indeed evaluate a procedure in the REPL and see what you get back:

```scm
+  ; ==> #<procedure:+>
l1 ; ==> ((#<procedure:sin> 3) (#<procedure:+> 1 2 3))
```

If `l1` were defined as `'((sin (+ 1 2)) (+ 1 2 3))` evaluating it would return `((sin (+ 1 2)) (+ 1 2 3))` so there is a big difference.

And of course. Using the quasiquote/unquote is just a fancy way of writing this:

```scm
(define l1 (list (list sin (+ 1 2))
                 (list + '1 '2 '3)))
```